# Restart android device in android 5.1

Tags: java, android

how to restart an android device programmatically and I used the below code to restart my device

```
       Process proc = null;

       try {
           //proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
             proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Could not reboot", ex);
        }
```

and for permission, I used this

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```

please help me and let me know if it is possible or not?
I need this on `android 5.1`

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the PowerManager to make it reboot.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot(java.lang.String)

or

There is a library to reboot the device. You can reboot with the following

```
code: Shell.SU.run("reboot");
```

Library : https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser